# Link Firebase phone verified account with Email Password

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Initially I was having **phone OTP** verification method to login into my application, later i have added **Email / Password** method to access the application. How do i merge or link or connect initial phone verified account data to new Email / Password account for the same user?

I want to access same user account by Phone verification and Email / password authentication in firebase realtime database. Is it possible to do?

**My firebase structure is like:**

```
- users
    -uid
        -name: "sam"
        -contact: 9999900000
        -age: 22
        
- books
    -uid    
        -bookid
            -bookname: "FOCUS"
            -price: 355
```

I should be able to access same uid instead of creating new one by different sign in method. Please help me to do this.

And i also want to avoid everytime login using phone verification, want just by using email password method. phone should not be mandatory

Comment: As I mentioned at the end of my answer, there is no need to delete any accounts. You just need to link them.

Comment: @AlexMamo Do i every time need linking while signing in via email??? or just first time in a lifetime?

Comment: You have o link an account only when you need to.

Comment: I mean i don't want to use phone verification when on everytime login if i'm using email password. New linked method should be sufficient to login when app reinstalled.